# In background script, listen for newly opened tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

In my background script, or anywhere but a content script, I am trying to listen for the active tab, or a newly opened tab.

I have this, but this is apparently incorrect:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to inject a content-script into the active tab. I don't want my content script to run for every tab/window, just for select tabs.

Does anyone know how to inject a content script for certain tabs? I can't figure it out. I assume the best way to inject content scripts is from the background script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to run a code in already activated tab ([chrome.tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query)):

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(foundTabs) {
    const activeTabId = foundTabs[0].id;

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeTabId, {
      file: 'inject.js'
    }); 
})
```

In case you want to inject a file into every newly activated tab ([chrome.tabs.onActivated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onActivated)):

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(function(activeInfo) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(activeInfo.tabId, {
        file: 'inject.js'
    }); 
});
```

Be sure to check if you have injected the file already, in order to prevent multiple injections.

For both cases, permissions should include `tabs`.

Comment: thanks, how do I know which tab was most recently clicked? Can I listen for tab clicks?

Comment: @Olegzandr, I think chrome.tabs.onActivated is right for that. Isn't it?

Comment: yes I think so, let me try it, if it works will accept answer!

Comment: btw, where do you see the `onActivated` API documented? I haven't seen that before

Comment: @Olegzandr, I put the link in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the:

```
 "webNavigation"
```

permission in manifest.json. After adding that permission, I now have:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(function (details) {

    const tabId = details.tabId;

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
      file: 'inject.js'
    });

});
```

now it works.

Comment: if there is a better way to determine the active tab without polling, please let me know

Answer (score -1):

some chrome API we cant access in content script in that case do that code in background.js and do according action from background js. if you want to do some action in content script in that case you need to communicate using send message